# How to handle the checkboxes using jQuery events in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have created one check box in my view file.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="country_checkbox" name="country_checkbox" value="0"/>show country
```

And in javascript file I have written the code to handle the check box, But that code is not at all invoking while changing the checkbox.

```
 $("#country_checkbox").click(function(){
    alert("this is called");
});
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: What you have here works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/50uu7yf9/. Check your console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: As Rory said, this works well. perhaps your script is being loaded prior all the DOM is ready. Wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function(...));` and give it a shot.